# Inject variables to external files from pom.xml using maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I want to populate some external files from the same project with some variables from pom.xml before the compilation phase.

```
<properties>
        <version.Var1>1.0.0-1</version.Var1>
        <version.Var2>1.0.0-2</version.Var2>
        <version.Var3>1.0.0-3</version.Var3>
</properties>
```

What is the best approach for doing that? Let's imagine that I have a file called versions.xml, and I want to use the previous versions(Var1,Var2,Var3) there.

I want to know which is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to import properties into project using:

[properties-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/index.html)

Comment: Thx Slawomir. I want to change some files from the project. Let's imagine that the project contains a file called .env and there I have some versions. I want to change the parameters from there using pom.xml before build. The difference is that there I have only some versions and I want something like "replace all".